# How to filter an array of generic type in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, objectmapper

I have a function to which I am sending an array of objects.
What I want to do is to filter this array of objects using their values, since the objects may not have common properties like name, age, etc.

```
func searchVC<T>(_ searchCriteria: String, _ modelArray: [T]) {
  let filteredArrayOfDict = modelArray.filter { $0.value == searchCriteria }

}
```

However this gives me below error :

```
Value of type 'T' has no member 'value'
```

My model classes are like :

```
class ABC : Mappable, CustomStringConvertible {
public private(set) var name : String?
public private(set) var age : Int?
public private(set) var abcArray : [ABCModelArray]

required init?(map: Map){
    name = ""
    age = -1
    mapping(map: map)
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    name <- map["Name"]
    age <- map["Age"]
}

  public var description: String{
}
}


class EFG : Mappable, CustomStringConvertible {
   public private(set) var type : String?
   public private(set) var code : Int?
   public private(set) var efgArray : [EFGModelArray]

   required init?(map: Map){
       type = ""
       code = -1
       mapping(map: map)
   }

   func mapping(map: Map) {
       type <- map["Type"]
       code <- map["Code"]
   }

   public var description: String{
 }
}
```

How can it be achieved?

Comment: Unclear what your code is supposed to do. You say `$0.value` but your model classes have no `value`. So what is that intended to mean? What is “using their values”? The phrase is nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

Since you yourself said, that these objects may not have a common property, you can't do it using plain generics. You'd need to constrain it to some protocol. For example :

```
protocol Filterable {
    var filterableValue: String
}
```

And then your method would look like this :

```
func searchVC(_ searchCriteria: String, _ modelArray: [Filterable]) {
  let filteredArrayOfDict = modelArray.filter { $0.filterableValue == searchCriteria }

}
```

You will of course need to conform to this protocol by all objects that could be passed here, and return appropriate `filterableValue` for each of them.

Comment: Okay. Now my model classes are already of type Mappable. For example. class EFG : Mappable {
    public private(set) var type : String?
    public private(set) var code : Int?
    } 
Even if I use Filterable protocol, how can i use it to acutally filter the objects?

Comment: Well, nothing stops you from conforming to multiple protocols. And then you’d have to return appropriate value for `filterableValue`. What is the end result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: If I conform to Filterable protocol,  it would add filterableValue property to my existing model classes which has no mapping. What I want however is make use of existing properties while searching and find whether a particular object `has a value`

Comment: But none of them have this `value` as they are. You can implement the `filterableValue` as a computed property and then return whatever you want for it. For example `var filterableValue: String { return "whatever" }`

Answer (score 1):

Yes but you need to make your type conform to `HasValue`

```
protocol HasValue {
    var value: String { get }
}
```

Example

```
struct Person: HasValue {
    let firstName: String
    let age: Int

    var value: String { return firstName }
}
```

Now you can define your function

```
func filter<Element:HasValue>(list: [Element], byKeyword keyword: String) -> [Element] {
    return list.filter { $0.value == keyword }
}
```